# No operator “+=” matches these operands

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have an h file where I have some class named `MainControl`, and a struct named `Vote`.

Inside MainControl I define a public operator in this way (this is a member function):

```
MainControl& operator+=(Vote& v);
```

In the matching .cpp file, I have this function:

```
MainControl& MainControl::operator+=(Vote& v){
...
}
```

When I try in another file to write something like this:

```
mc+=v
```

Where `mc` is an object from the class MainControl and v an object from the struct `Vote`.

I get this error:

```
 error C2679: binary '+=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Vote' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

I did include the correct files I belive, as I have a very similar operator working for me (Instead of the struct `Vote` it involves another class).

I have no idea what causes this, can anyone help?

EDIT:

The operator is used this way:

```
mc += Vote(vr1, "Cyprus");
```

Where `mc` is from the class `MainControl`.

The struct Vote looks like this:

```
struct Vote
{
    Voter voter;
    string* voted_state;
    // ALL is public here.

    Vote(Voter current_voter, string state1, string state2 = "", string state3 = "", string state4 = "", string state5 = "", string state6 = "", string state7 = "", string state8 = "", string state9 = "", string state10 = "") :
        voter(current_voter), voted_state(new string[VOTE_ARRAY_SIZE]){
        voted_state[0] = state1;
        voted_state[1] = state2;
        voted_state[2] = state3;
        voted_state[3] = state4;
        voted_state[4] = state5;
        voted_state[5] = state6;
        voted_state[6] = state7;
        voted_state[7] = state8;
        voted_state[8] = state9;
        voted_state[9] = state10;
    }
    ~Vote() {
        delete[] voted_state;
    }
};
```

In the similar operation that doesn't give me compilation errors, the operator is used this way:

```
mc += p1
```

Where `p1` is an object from a class name participant, and mc an object from the class `MainControl`.

In the .h file where I define the class `MainControl` I have this decleation:

```
MainControl& operator+=(Participant& p);
```

The class participant looks like this:

```
class Participant
{
    string state_name;
    string song_name;
    int time_length;
    string singer_name;
    bool is_registered;
public:
    Participant(string state, string song, int time, string singer):
    state_name(state),song_name(song),singer_name(singer),time_length(time),is_registered(false){
    }
    ~Participant() = default;
    string state() const;
    string song() const;
    int timeLength() const;
    string singer() const;
    int isRegistered() const; 
    void update(const string song, const int time, const string singer);
    void updateRegistered(const bool status);
};
```

`p1` was defined this way:

```
Participant p1("USA", "Song_USA", 175, "Singer_USA");
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195005/discussion-on-question-by---no-operator--matches-these-operands).

Answer (score 0):

your += operator takes a (non-const) l-value reference

```
MainControl& operator+=(Vote& v);
```

then you are passing a r-value to it:

```
mc += Vote(vr1, "Cyprus");
```

this is not convertable to a (non-const) l-value reference

if you (as stated) need to modify "Vote" during this operation you can do the following:

```
auto v1 = Vote(vr1, "Cyprus");
mc += v1;
```

this way you may pass Vote to the operator as you intend.

But:
This is not a good design and will bite you later on.